# PHP Parse Date From String

Tags: php, string, date, timezone, format

I received a date string from API respond like this

> "2013-07-09T04:58:23.075Z"

How can I parse that string, say to change format to

> 2013-07-09 [04:58:23]

The time indeed is not based on my local time, I think the .075Z should change something about the time.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do that using the `DateTime object`.

```
$Date = new DateTime('2013-07-09T04:58:23.075Z'); //create dateTime object
$Date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Amsterdam')); //set the timezone

echo $Date->format('d/m/Y H:i');
```

Comment: It seems it works. it knows because of 75Z mean 75 minutes from UTC or GMT sort of time?

Comment: @Ardeus The .075 is 75 microseconds and the Z (pronounced Zulu) indicates the time is in UTC.

Comment: .075 is miliseconds (not microseconds).

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
$date = '2013-07-09T04:58:23.075Z';
$seconds = strtotime($date);

echo date('Y-m-d [H:i:s]', $seconds);
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: And what about the timezone?

Answer (score 1):

```
$time = "2013-07-09T04:58:23.075Z";
$exp = explode('T',$time);
echo $exp[0] .' [' .substr($exp[1], 0, -5) . ']';
```

I'm using it like this.

Answer (score -1):

@Benz

simply add below:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Brisbane');

echo date('d/m/Y H:i', strtotime('2013-07-09T04:58:23.075Z'));
```

were done! Hope this help.